# In Next.js, how to scroll to top of window after setting search value on a search bar?

Tags: reactjs, search, input, scroll, next.js

Imagine I have a button somewhere. When clicked, the text on it, now goes to my search bar. How do I make the window scroll to the search bar too after the value is set in the `Input` element shown below?

```js
          <Flex
            flexDirection="column"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            maxWidth="90%"
            mt={4}
          >
            {!filteredBlogPosts.length && 'No posts found.'}
            {filteredBlogPosts.map((frontMatter) => (
              <>
              <BlogPost
                key={frontMatter.title + frontMatter.lastPublishedOn}
                 handleSearch={(anyKey) => setSearchValue(anyKey)}
                 // Insert your code here, how to scroll after setting the key to search? 
                {...frontMatter}
              />
              </>
            ))}
          </Flex>
```

And, here is the `<Input>` field

```js
            <Input
              aria-label="Search"
              borderColor="blue.500"
              onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Search"
              value={searchValue}
              //or should I do scroll here? How?
              autoFocus
              onFocus={e => e.currentTarget.select()}
            />
```

Is this something easy to do? Please present code examples if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces this issue in the future, I solved it using this simple function.

```js
    const scrollSearch = myKey => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    frontMatter.handleSearch(myKey)
  };
```

And passed the `scrollSearch` function in button `onClick`.